# Two Instances of Same Activity with viewpager runs at the same time

Tags: java, android, memory, garbage-collection

I have this strange problem where i have an activity B which i start using start Activity method from Activity A and when i call finish() in activity B,It will it close

when i start  activity B again from activity A, It seems like previous instance and as well as current instance is active in memory but if i close the app and start it again it works fine only for the first time

when i start activity B second time it does not work as expected 
How do prevent the previous instance to run, only the new instance to be running in memory?

Comment: there is something wrong with your code for sure.

Comment: i have to say , people on stackoverflow try to find mistakes on questions asked rather than willing to help as downvoting helps them gain reputation

Comment: I have to surprise you. Dovnvoting reduces dovnvoters reputation as well. So it **harms** their reputation. The reason of dovnvotes here is low question quality. Your question is too abstract to help you. And I gave you the same abstract comment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try flags?

```
Intent(context, BActivity::class.java)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
```